# How to round a formula without creating another column?

Tags: excel-formula

This is the formula (To calculate vat prices) is located in cell G7

=D7*$G$1+D7

I would like to add the ROUNDUP(G7,2) to its cell so that the results are rounded to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put the Formula contained in G7 in brackets and insert it.

```
=ROUNDUP((D7*$G$1+D7),2)
```